# DynamoDB - How to "break" hierarchy without using relationships?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Consider the following JSON DynamoDB representation for a project management software.

```
Application = {
  "Users" : [
    "user1" : {"name" : "john"},
    "user2" : {"name" : "jack"}
  ]
  "Projects" : [
    "project1" : {
      "users" : [
        "user1",
        "user2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A project can have many users and a user can have many projects.

In Projects>project1>users, is using the user key/id recommended? The way I see is that I'm simulating a tradional relationship and not really utilizing DynamoDB the right way.

I've read the guide about many-to-many relationships [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html) but honestly I just can't understand their visual schema or explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the database to represent relationships, like between users and projects, especially when you are having many to many relationship, you could consider using a Graph database like AWS Neptune instead. Admittedly Graph databases can seem a bit scary and theoretical to start with.

You are right that in DynamoDB you would be using the user ID in the projects table and then make a lookup in the Users table to get the users for a given project.
The reason it seems that this is not utilizing DynamoDB correctly is that DynamoDB is essentially only a key value store. Granted the values can be quite complex, but you cannot natively model any relations between keys.

DynamoDB now supports transactions so you can query multiple tables in one atomic transaction if needed.

If you find that you are having many relations like that, you should look at using a relational or graph database instead.

Comment: Well the only reason I am using DynamoDB is because of how cheap it is compared to a relational database in AWS that you pay for it like a EC2 machine. And is not really multiple tables, my idea is to put both in them in the same DynamoDB table, just adjacent to each other.

Comment: Yeah I get that. Perhaps you can look at [Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) where you only pay for storage and transactions, but admittedly the pricing will be a bit difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

This a complex topic and i could't possibly explain it all in this answer, but I can point you to some excellent resources that should provide you with answers as they go over this topic in detail.

**Video:** [AWS re:Invent 2018: Amazon DynamoDB Deep Dive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k) - I suggest watching the whole thing to fully understand the concept, but you could skip to 45:42 to jump strait to the part about hierarchical data molding.